# Count MAX consecutive values with multiple criteria

Tags: google-sheets, max, frequency, array-formulas

I want to get max consecutive values to count with multiple criteria. I found this formula online

```
=ArrayFormula(MAX(FREQUENCY(IF($B$2:$B="WIN",ROW($B$2:$B)),IF($B$2:$B<>"WIN",ROW($B$2:$B)))))
```

and it works great for one criterion, counting "win" and/or "buy" by itself. But I want to get max consecutive count when 2 criteria are met at the same time, sort of cross-reference.

[image: sample pic]

Like in the above example I want a max consecutive count of "buy" which by itself is 5, and "win" which by itself is 4. But I want the max consecutive count of when they occur together, which is only 2 times in the above example.

I tried modifying this formula in different ways but never got the correct result.

Here's [sample doc](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15iMlnXG440CPH42QzEIMe8WbTKwzhKsdtmaM4frvu-Y/edit?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to combine the conditions for "Buy" and "Win" with a multiplication in the array formula to get an AND. Then you need to negate that expression in the second part of the FREQUENCY. You could either use NOT with the same expression:

```
=ArrayFormula(MAX(FREQUENCY(IF((A2:A="Buy")*($B$2:$B="WIN"),ROW($B$2:$B)),IF(not((A2:A="Buy")*($B$2:$B="WIN")),ROW($B$2:$B)))))
```

or use a bit of Boolean logic to convert it to an OR expression using addition as below:

```
=ArrayFormula(MAX(FREQUENCY(IF((A2:A="Buy")*($B$2:$B="WIN"),ROW($B$2:$B)),IF((A2:A<>"Buy")+($B$2:$B<>"WIN"),ROW($B$2:$B)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly Tom, as usual. Thank you.

Comment: Tom how can I get an average of the above example. Like for "win" an average of events would be 1+1+1+2+4 (consecutive values, win+win+win+win,win+win,win,win,win, because there are 3 single "win" + 2 consecutive  "win" and finally 4 consecutive "win" at the bottom) = 9 divided by number of occurances, in this case 5 would give us 1.8 . in the case of "win & buy" an average of events would be 1+1+1+1+2 =6 divided by number of occuranses, in this case 5 also would give us 1.2 . Thank you.

Comment: I hope this isn't being too picky, but I feel this would be better as a separate question. The issue in the original question is about multiple criteria, but the follow-up question is only one criterion. The issue will be how to remove any zeroes from the calculation so you get the right answer for the average.

Comment: I will post it as separate question then. Thank you very much @Tom.